# Angled divider with image in section below

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am working on doing an slice, or angled edge with my React app. I am using tailwinds css however using some custom CSS I managed to get it done. However, while its doing the slice, i would like it to be filled with the div below it instead of white.

Is that possible?

Here is my CSS

```
 .angle--bottom-right {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 2vw), 0 100%);
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 2vw), 0 100%);
  }
  
  @supports not ((-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 7vw), 0 100%)) or (clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 7vw), 0 100%))) {
    .angle--bottom-right::before, .angle--bottom-right::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 10;
      display: block;
      border-style: solid;
    }
    .angle--bottom-right::after {
      bottom: 0;
      border-width: 0 0 8vw 100vw;
      border-color: transparent transparent transparent transparent;
    }
  }
```

Here is what I happening

[image]

The white triangle I want to be filled with the DIV that is below it.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use clip-path in this situation I'm afraid. The body background will show through in the area exposed.